# Why was John Brown's raid on Harper's Ferry treason?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution

In Article 3 Section 3 of the Constitution, it says that

> Treason against the United States, shall consist only in levying War against them, or in adhering to their Enemies, giving them Aid and Comfort.

So I understand, maybe, how arming people to hurt others is treason because the "others" who will be hurt are Americans. So is it treason if, for example, a gun store owner provides a gun to someone s/he knows will use it to hurt others? I'm sure that's *something*, maybe indirect murder or something, but is it treason? If not, why was John Brown's raid treason?

Comment: I wonder to what extent your sense that Brown was fighting the first skirmish of the Civil War enters into why you even thought of this question. I would point out and forgive me is this is obvious, that nobody at that time even imagined the war between the states that would occur 2 years later I don't think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section three of article three of the US Constitution states:

> Treason against the United States, shall consist only in levying War against them, or in adhering to their Enemies, giving them Aid and Comfort. No Person shall be convicted of Treason unless on the Testimony of two Witnesses to the same overt Act, or on Confession in open Court.

The Congress shall have Power to declare the Punishment of Treason, but no Attainder of Treason shall work Corruption of Blood, or Forfeiture except during the Life of the Person attainted.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Three_of_the_United_States_Constitution[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Three_of_the_United_States_Constitution)

John Brown was planning to overthrow the governments of the slave states or force them to abolish slavery.

Article four section four says:

> The United States shall guarantee to every State in this Union a Republican Form of Government,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Four_of_the_United_States_Constitution[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Four_of_the_United_States_Constitution)

If John Brown's abolitionist group seized control of a state's government it could be considered turning it into a non republican form of government.  Thus the federal government might be forced to intervene, thus members of John Brown's group could expect that they might get involved in a civil war against the United states, thus "levying War against them" and committing treason.

> [...] and [the United States] shall protect each of them [the States] against Invasion; and on Application of the Legislature, or of the Executive (when the Legislature cannot be convened) against domestic Violence.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Four_of_the_United_States_Constitution[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Four_of_the_United_States_Constitution)

John Brown's followers should have been able to imagine that they constituted an invasion of Virginia, and that by planning a slave rebellion they were planning large scale domestic violence.  Thus they should have been able to imagine that the federal government would be obligated to try to stop them and thus that their plans would likely result in "levying War against them" (the United states) and thus committing treason.

And of course the plan involved seizing the federal arsenal at Harper's Ferry that could be considered "levying War against them" (the United states) and thus committing treason.  Just as members of a dependent Indian tribe would be guilty of treason by attacking a federal fort or Indian agency or as southerners were guilty of treason when seizing federal arsenals, forts, and other installations.

And in fact President Buchanan ordered 90 marines from the US Navy Yard in Washington DC to Harper's Ferry where they defeated John Brown's raiders under the command of Lieutenant Colonel Robert E. Lee of the Second United states Cavalry.

So John Brown and his followers were guilty of treason against the United States.

But John Brown and his followers were tried and convicted for Treason against the Commonwealth of Virginia, murder, and inciting a slave insurrection.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_v._John_Brown[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_v._John_Brown)

And that kind of gets my goat.  I can't help thinking that President Buchanan should have had Brown extradited to the District of Columbia to be charged with Treason against the United States.

IMHO the US constitution should be amended to say that no government dependent on the United states, such as a state, or Indian tribe, or county, or municipality, etc. etc. that ever committed in the past or commits in the future treason against the United States, shall ever again be able to have a statute defining a crime of treason against itself.  And furthermore, if any official of any dependent government prosecutes, convicts, or punishes someone for treason against that dependent government while that dependent government is committing treason against the United States, that official shall be guilty of violating the civil rights of the persons so charged, and shall suffer penalties proscribed by federal law for violatign civil rights, or else penalties equal to the total of all the penalties inflicted upon every person he prosecutes, convicts, or punishes for treason against that traitorous dependent government, whichever is harsher.

Comment: Kind of a moot point about whether he committed treason against Virginia or the Feds (he did both) seeing as how Virginia convicted and hanged him. The greater point would be his ability to get a fair trial in pro-slave Virginia. I don't know how that last paragraph is relevant, this all happened in 1859, two years before Virginia joined the Confederacy.

Comment: Your last paragraph also seems to go against the spirit of the Constitution's law on treason, which specifically forbids charges of treason from staining the person's bloodline ("no Attainder of Treason shall work Corruption of Blood").  Leveling permanent penalties on a state for one instance of its government committing treason seems to be the state-level equivalent of attainder.

Comment: Schwern - but some of the rebel states did execute people for treason if they refused to help the treason of those states during the Rebellion.

Comment: IllusiveBrian - 1) A state is not a person and thus has no human rights to be violated. 2) A state lasts for generation after generation, century after century.  Thus punishing a state in 2063 for what it did in 1863 would not be corrupting the blood of the descendants of the 1863 state because a state has no descendants and it would still be the same original guilty state.  3) removing a state's ability to make treason laws because it misused them in the past would be protecting future state residents, not punishing the state.

Comment: IllusiveBrian - 4) no state needs the ability to make treason laws because it seems impossible to imagine an action that actually was treason against a state that was not also treason against the United states and punishable by federal laws.  And it is very easy to imagine a state making false accusations of treason against it that were totally invalid, since that happened in 1861-1865.  My proposal seems a little less sweeping that abolishing every state's ability to have treason laws.

Answer (score 9):

John Brown [led a raid on a US military arsenal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Brown%27s_raid_on_Harpers_Ferry) as part of an attempt to start an armed rebellion against the current established order.  That's essentially waging war against the US government and at least attempting to aid enemies (as any slaves in revolt would be.)  So by that token, it should be easy to understand why a charge of "treason" was reasonable.

His [defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_v._John_Brown) didn't particularly dispute that very well.  People who supported him did so mainly not due to belief in his innocence but rather abhorrence for the institution that he was attacking.

TL;DR - He was essentially guilty of treason, but some felt that treason against an unjust institution was a moral act.

Answer (score 1):

"Treason against the United States, shall consist..."

Nowadays, when we talk about the "United States," we talk about a whole country, the US of A.

But at the time of founding, and for some time thereafter, the "United States" meant "a bunch of individual states that were united."

It's not clear to me, at least, that John Brown was committing treason against the "United States" (as we now know it).But Brown was committing "treason" against a single state, Virginia. And he was clearly committing murder. So he was guilty of at least two out of the three charges.

In any event, he was tried, convicted and hanged by [Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_v._John_Brown), not the United States. Such "Federal" troops as were involved, under people like Robert E. Lee and "Jeb" Stuart, were all southerners, and mostly Virginians, who would soon have their own fight against "Federal" troops. Ironically, the trial and hanging took place in a part of the future *West* Virginia, which would "secede" from secession."

To answer your other question, a gun seller is not supposed to sell a gun that s/he knows *for sure,* will be used to hurt others. If it's merely a suspicion, that would be different, legally.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a store owner selling weapons to someone who then turns around and acts against the people and John Brown is that one engages in legal commerce of goods vs. someone who hands out weapons for the purpose of insurrection.

It might be argued that John Brown's trial was politically motivated. That Brown's actions in the powder keg that was the antebellum years had to be punished severely to avoid such actions being repeated.

So, if you want to buy thousands of weapons for yourself and your friends, do it.
If you then take those weapons and hand them out to groups of people to protest/ demand/ impose some legal change/ commit crimes, you might be tried for treason.